# Jmeter Reports do not get generated if there are errors if the Jmeter Test executed using Jmeter Maven Plugin

Tags: maven-3, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am running Jmeter tests using Jmeter Maven Plugin. After I run the test I want to generate simple reports that indicate if the tests passed/failed. I referred to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669467/jmeter-how-to-create-summary-report-from-jtl-file?lq=1

for generating the reports. I have added a shell script to generate html reports from the jmeter jtl result files.Then I use the exec-maven plugin to execute the script that in turn generates the html report files.So far Everything works fine. The problem that I am facing is that if one of the Jmeter tests fails then the report isn't generated at all. 
So I am assuming that maven exits once it detects error in the test-suites and doesn't execute the exec-maven plugin and hence the shell script isnt called at all.

Can someone give me directions on this? Is there any property in the pom file or any settings that I can try to get around this. Any help would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the **<ignoreResultFailures>** configuration setting to true to make the plugin ignore the failures and continue executing everything else.

```
+---+
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
+---+
```